# how to enlarge a div on hover without moving other div

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position

I'm looking to achieve a hover effect like [this hover](http://shopper.queldorei.com/index.php/women/dresses.html) where the image enlarges but does not displace the surrounding divs.  I have seen this done by assigning relative and absolute positioning and a z-index but that isn't working for me.  Perhaps I assigned those values to the wrong classes.  My code is below...any help is appreciated

I wasn't totally sure how to post the code here so...my site (and code problem) can be viewed [here](http://4ucaps.activo.com/fitted/mlb/?dir=desc&order=position)

It's my first time posting here.  Thanks for the instruction.  Here is the code...

HTML:

```
<div class="products-container">
   <div class="products-container-inner">
      <div class="item">
      <div class="item">
      <div class="item">
      <div class="item">
```

CSS:

```
div.item {
    height: 135px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

div.item:hover {
    border: none; float: left;
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease;
    -o-transition: .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: .2s ease;
    transition: .2s ease;
}

div.products-container-inner {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.item .product-name {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

div.item:hover .product-name {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

div.item .price-box {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

div.item:hover .price-box {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

div.item .btn {     
    background-color: #EE432E;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EE432E 0%, #C63929 50%, #B51700 50%, #891100 100%);
    border: 1px solid #951100;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 115, 100, 0.4) inset, 0 1px 3px #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal 16px/1 "helvetica neue",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 65px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
}

div.item:hover .btn {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F37873;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F37873 0%, #DB504D 50%, #CB0500 50%, #A20601 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.item:active .btn {
    background-color: #D43C28;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #D43C28 0%, #AD3224 50%, #9C1500 50%, #700D00 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 115, 100, 0.4) inset;
}
```

Comment: I appear to need login details to see the code, could you post it instead? Also, the example you linked to uses two separate `div`s, which are set to `display:none;` or `display:block;` dependent on whether they're hovered over or not.

Comment: You can post code (though it's best to narrow it down as much as possible) by pasting it directly into the question box, then highlighting it and pressing CTRL+K (to mark it as code).  You can also put up an interactive example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

In your example of what you want to achieve... There is two divs for the same pic.
One "regular" and one "hover" that only appears on hover.
This hidden one as a z-index of 2 and is shown over the first... Wich give that impression of a resising div. But it's not the case.
;)

===
EDIT:
ok Ryh, see this start I've done for you here...
Without jQuery, you will not have any "shiny effects" like fadein/fadeout...
But, it may be a choice to do it like this :

CSS:

```
  div.item {width:200px;}
  div.hover {display:none; position:relative; z-index:2; top:-200px; width:300px;}

  // The top:-200px is to move the big image up... depends on the small pic height.
  // And the width are in fonction of the pics width.
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="item" id="img1" onmouseover="showbigger(this.id);">
  <img src="something.jpg" style='width;200px; height:200px; border:1px solid black;'>
  </div>

  <div class="hover" id="img1big" onmouseout="shownormal(this.id);">
  <img src="something-bigger.jpg" style='width;300px; height:300px; border:1px solid black;'>
  </div>

  <script>
  function showbigger(ref){
  document.getElementById(ref+'big').style.display='inline';
  }

  function shownormal(ref){
  document.getElementById(ref).style.display='none';
  }
  </script>
```

You'll have to play a little with positioning and pic sizes.
And this may not a perfect solution... but it's a start if you want to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting...I would like to achieve this with one div tho.  maybe this fiddle is a better example....only I would like to achieve the effect without jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/jKTVn/5/

Comment: I added an example... Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I see where you're going here.  What are you calling on with the id's of img1 and img1big?

Comment: I call showbigger() or shownormal() with "this.id" as argument.<br/> So i'm calling showbigger("img1") or shownormal("img1big") and they both affect something-bigger.jpg style.display (on/off switch).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this without using two divs by "zooming in" on the element using

```
element:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

Html for a hyperlink:

```
<a href="/index.html"  onclick="createPopup">Click Here</a>
```

Css

```
a{text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  color: #0000ff;
}

a:hover { text-decoration: initial;
    color: #ff0000;     
}

a:visited {color: #b200ff;}
```